# How to assign a null value in xml soapui

Tags: xml, soap, xsd, soapui

I am creating a mock response using soapUI. In the response a certain element may or may not have a value (depending on the input sent by the user). I would like to assign this element a null value if the user has not sent anything to populate it with. I have tried using the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute but that ends up turning the whole value as null despite the user sending a value to populate it with. I have then tried `nillable="true"` but instead of assigning the value of null when the user hasn't sent anything, it assigns the value as empty strings; `""`. I would like to explicitly let it have the value of `null` if no user input has been given.

Comment: Would you please show sample input and desired xmls?

Comment: The input comes from an external application and the input gets sent to the soapUI mock (mocking our server/database). In the response, I have an element of `<p214:traffic nillable="true">${awardEndDate2}</p214:traffic>` in which I populate the placeholder to a value if the user send an input. If the user doesn't send an input, then im trying to dynamically add the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute to it

Comment: Hope you gone thru the question and appreciate if you could reply with requested information. At least a sample data with resembles yours so that it would be easy for you to adopt to your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping this to the tag

```
${= "${awardEndDate2}"!=""?"${awardEndDate2}"?"null"}
```

The quotes with ${awardEndDate2} are because to avoid errors if `awardEndDate2` parameter has spaces in it.